# Is it possible to find when was the audio mixer opened or used the last time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

Today when I unlocked my computer, the audio mixer was open and I don't remember opening it last time I used the computer. Is it possible to know when was the last time I used it, and what was changed ?
This question could seems strange but I don't know what happenned.

Comment: Check History>>>>C:\Users\Your User Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

Comment: Immediately closed when I opened it